# fullpage.js : the height cuts the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I'm trying to adapt the jquery script fullpage.js on a (french) cms "SPIP" (http://spip.net).

It's a script to create a one page website with horizontal and vertical navigation.

I have a bug with the horizontal navigation. Text are cut before the end. The height depends of the height of the window.

I have to resize twice the window to be abble to read all the text.

what can i do ?

Here the website : http://gilleskleinformations.fr/?var_mode=recalcul (see "blognotes").

(i'm a dummy with javascript)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got **scrollOverflow: true** and you've included the **jquery.slimscroll.min.js** so it should work.

However, I noticed you are loading **jquery.slimscroll.min.js** before loading **jQuery**.

Try loading the **jquery.slimscroll.min.js** just before the **jquery.fullPage.js** but after **jquery.min.js** since the plugin requires jQuery so something like this:

```
<!-- jQuery and jQuery UI -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Plugins -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="squelettes/vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="squelettes/js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
```

[fullpage.js manual](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs)

Comment: Hi alvaro ! Thank's a lot too; Are you the creator of fullpage ?